# how to set selected dropdown list in html

Tags: dropdownbox

this is my code for dropdown list,plz guide me.

```
<div class = "form-inline">
  <label class = "">Situation</label>
  <select selected="" name="sit" id="situ" class='form-control'style="margin-left: 30px; width: 145px;">
    <option value="" >select</option>
    <?
    if ($situation != '') {
    $revise = $situation;
    }
    foreach ($revise as $row):
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['situation']; ?></option>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: <? endforeach; ?> ???

Comment: @dinever $situation is the array of dropdown list taken from database

Comment: @ray it is the end tag for foreach loop...just like  for each{......}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the item you want selected for a dropdown list, add the attribute `selected`.

Eg.

```
<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

In this case, 1 will be selected.

To get the value of this dropdown after form submit, it depends on the method of your form being *POST* or *GET*.

In this example, I'm assuming it's POST. `<form method="POST">`

```
<div class = "form-inline">
  <label class = "">Situation</label>
  <select selected="" name="sit" id="situ" class='form-control'style="margin-left: 30px; width: 145px;">
    <option value="" >select</option>
    <?
    if (isset($_POST['sit']))
        $selected = $_POST['sit'];
    if ($situation != '') {
    $revise = $situation;
    }
    foreach ($revise as $row):
        $selectedHTML = '';
        if (isset($selected) && $row['id'] == $selected)
            $selectedHTML = ' selected="selected"';
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"<?= $selectedHTML; ?>><?= $row['situation']; ?></option>
    <? endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

You can try something like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['sit']))
  $selected = $_POST['sit'];
```

What this does is check if `$_POST['sit']` value is found. If yes then we'll make that `$selected`, else we'll leave it.

```
$selectedHTML = '';
if (isset($selected) && $row['id'] == $selected)
  $selectedHTML = ' selected="selected"';
```

And then in the foreach loop, we will first initialize `$selectedHTML` as empty string. It will not add anything to `<option>` unless it got its value changed.

We will check if `$selected` is defined or not and if it is, we will check if the current value of `$row['id']` within the foreach loop is equal to the submitted value which is `$selected`. If so, we will set `$selectedHTML` which will add `selected="selected"` only to the current `<option>`.